# Move the content of TD in another TD in the same table

Tags: jquery, append

I have **many tables and for each one** I need to move the content of td.risultato into td.squadre (they are in the same row).

I am using this, but it's not working

```
$('table.pronostico td.risultato span').each(function() {
  $(this).appendTo('table.pronostico td.squadre');
});
```

Any help?

UPDATE with code

```
<table class="pronostico">  
<tr>
    <td class="squadre">some stuff here</td>
    <td class="risultato"><span>2</span></td>
</tr></table>
```

The span should move inside td.squadre

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54133916/edit) and create a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```js
$('table.pronostico td.risultato span').each(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").find(".squadre").append($(this)); // use $(this).clone(1) to copy the span
});
```

```css
.squadre { background-color:red }
.risultato { background-color:green }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="pronostico">
  <tr>
    <td class="squadre">Original content. </td>
    <td class="risultato">Move the span: <span>hello 1</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="squadre">Original content. </td>
    <td class="risultato">Move the span: <span>hello 2</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="squadre">Original content. </td>
    <td class="risultato">Move the span: <span>hello 3</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr/>
<table class="pronostico">
  <tr>
    <td class="squadre">Original content. </td>
    <td class="risultato">Move the span: <span>hello 1</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="squadre">Original content. </td>
    <td class="risultato">Move the span: <span>hello 2</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr/>
<table class="pronostico">
  <tr>
    <td class="squadre">Original content. </td>
    <td class="risultato">Move the span: <span>hello 1</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Using appendTo**

```js
$('table.pronostico td.risultato span').each(function() {
  $(this).appendTo(
    $('.squadre',$(this).closest("tr"))
  )
});
```

```css
.squadre { background-color:red }
.risultato { background-color:green }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="pronostico">
  <tr>
    <td class="squadre">Original content. </td>
    <td class="risultato">Move the span: <span>hello 1</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="squadre">Original content. </td>
    <td class="risultato">Move the span: <span>hello 2</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="squadre">Original content. </td>
    <td class="risultato">Move the span: <span>hello 3</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr/>
<table class="pronostico">
  <tr>
    <td class="squadre">Original content. </td>
    <td class="risultato">Move the span: <span>hello 1</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="squadre">Original content. </td>
    <td class="risultato">Move the span: <span>hello 2</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr/>
<table class="pronostico">
  <tr>
    <td class="squadre">Original content. </td>
    <td class="risultato">Move the span: <span>hello 1</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In your example I see just 1 table with many rows. I have MANY tables and just 1 row each

Comment: My code works for many tables, any number of rows. See update

Comment: Almost there :)  The original content of td.squadre disappears. Shouldnt "appendTo" be used instead?

Comment: You said MOVE, so I MOVE. Remove the line with empty to keep the span content

Comment: I am now COPYING the SPAN to the TD

Comment: Sorry but I am talking about the original content of td.squadre. It must remain there and not be overwritten by the td.risultato span

Comment: See update. I copy the span and append the copy to the cell - you may need to append a leading space to the span

Comment: Perfect! I've added $(this).empty(); to your last update and it works. Thank you!

Comment: No. If you want to MOVE, then do not clone. The append will move. I will update again

Comment: I have added an example for appendTo